# Error: Unable to compile C-ABI query code. Make sure native software development toolchain is installed on your system

Tags: java, glibc, quarkus

I recently started reading about Quarkus, and and followed their documentation to BUILDING A NATIVE EXECUTABLE, but got stuck with 2nd step in the prerequisites:

- JDK 8 installed with JAVA_HOME configured appropriately
- A working C development environment
- GraalVM version 19.3.1 installed and configured appropriately
- A working container runtime (Docker, podman)

  `A working C development environment`, check out the documentation in the link https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image

I'm using a windows machine and I understand the complexity of setting up the environment on it, according to what I read on the internet, I've install `GCC, and the glibc and zlib headers.`
I was able to install `GCC` after a painful process, but because I'm not familiar with `glibc` and `zlib` installiation process, I kind of stuck now, This is the error I'm getting when I tried to run   `./mvnw package -Pnative` command :

```
[getting-started-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:22928]        setup:     539.69 ms,  1.50 GB
Error: Unable to compile C-ABI query code. Make sure native software development toolchain is installed on your system.
com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Unable to compile C-ABI query code. Make sure native software development toolchain is installed on your system.
        at com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:79)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.c.codegen.CCompilerInvoker.compileAndParseError(CCompilerInvoker.java:103)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.c.CAnnotationProcessor.compileQueryCode(CAnnotationProcessor.java:131)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.c.CAnnotationProcessor.process(CAnnotationProcessor.java:84)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.c.NativeLibraries.finish(NativeLibraries.java:387)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.processNativeLibraryImports(NativeImageGenerator.java:1514)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.setupNativeLibraries(NativeImageGenerator.java:1010)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.setupNativeImage(NativeImageGenerator.java:841)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:528)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$run$0(NativeImageGenerator.java:445)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1386)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "CL" (in directory "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-xxxx"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.c.codegen.CCompilerInvoker.startCommand(CCompilerInvoker.java:158)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.c.codegen.CCompilerInvoker.startCompiler(CCompilerInvoker.java:140)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.c.codegen.CCompilerInvoker.compileAndParseError(CCompilerInvoker.java:71)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:444)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:139)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
        ... 16 more
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  14.150 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-03-16T09:56:56-05:00
```

Answer (score 2):

First, if you build on Windows, better use GraalVM 20 with Quarkus 1.3.0.Final as they fixed a lot of things in GraalVM 20. We released the Core last week so if you use the `quarkus-bom` instead of the `quarkus-universe-bom`, you can already use it. Otherwise, the full release will come as early as Thursday.

Next, we had someone working on contributing some notes about how to build GraalVM native executables on Windows here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/7871/files .

Could you have a look at these notes, test them and provide feedback in the PR (be it if they work or not)?

Comment: As of now, I'm using `quarkus-universe-bom`. As per my understanding, you are suggesting to use `quarkus-bom` ?

Comment: I'm using  GraalVM 20 with Quarkus 1.3.0.Final, and updated pom file to use `quarkus-bom`, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions in the PR I mentioned?

Comment: I followed the instructions, but got the same result @Guillaume Smet

Comment: After days of struggle with Windows machine, I gave up on it and switched into Ubuntu, I installed VirtualBox on Windows machine and setup Ubuntu image, the setup process went very smooth, I installed Java, maven, curl, GraalVM, Spring, C environment etc ... from command line like a piece of cake.
After days of struggle with Windows machine, I gave up on it and switched into Ubuntu, I installed VirtualBox on Windows machine and setup Ubuntu image, the setup process went very smooth, I installed Java, maven, curl, GraalVM, Spring, C environment etc .from command line like a piece of cake.

Comment: `call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" && mvn package -Pnative` did the job.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run "x86 Native Ttool Command Prompt for VC2017", and got past the native tool chain error.

But now I have a linker error. Question incoming.